# Layout manipulation , from code

Tags: android, android-layout

Let say we are in landscape and I have one root container
in that container other two(smaller). I want at run time to swap places of cotainers. The container A to go to the place of B and B to go to the place of the layout A.

My layout is defined in xml. So what is the best way to make two element to swap places ?
Is is good to change the properties of for example RelativeLayout.LayoutParams ?

First of all for scenario like this , what is the best layout to be used for the root container ?

after the call of `setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);`
and after `root=findViewById(R.id.root); , a=findViewById(R.id.a);, b=findViewById(R.id.b);`

should I remove the child views from the root layout ?
like root.removeallview(); ? or there is something else that I should do ?

I need someone with experience to explain me how should this kind of things done, of course evry suggestion is welcomed and if you have some useful links please share with me.

I want to be able to swap between this two different ways of presenting the layouts.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put these views into [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html), then you can move the fragments around using a [FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by setting alignParentLeft and alignParentRight with the LayoutParams.

If I were you I would probably take a different approach though. I would create my "main" layout that is just the top level container. Then create seperate xml files that represent all of the different layout configurations that you want to include in the app. At runtime use the LayoutInflator to inflate the xml file that you want to use into an object and add it to your parent layout with `mainLayout.addView(child);`